# load() + Lightbox doesn't work on IE 8 only

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

This time, it's a little bit different from my previous posts. So I decide to make a new one.

FYI, I use Lightbox plugin from this:
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

ePC.html = contain an image with lightbox effect (work with IE, Chrome, Firefox).

reviews.html = Home page. connect to scripts/script.js. (Contain the .load() function, loading ePhone.html or ePC.html by clicking on one of those 3 links).  Please Ignore "ePhone.html".
Below is the scripts/script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //ePhone link is clicked. Open ePhone.html PLEASE IGNORE THIS LINK.
    $('#linkEPhone').click(function() {
        $('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html');
    });

    //ePC link is clicked. Open ePC.html
    $('#linkEPC').click(function() {
        $('#apDiv2').load('ePC.html', function () {
             $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
       });

    });

    //ePC2 link is clicked. Open the <div> section of ePC.html. The image is located inside the <div> section.
    $('#linkEPC2').click(function() {
                $('#apDiv2').load('ePC.html #content', function () {
                 $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
                 $.getScript('js/jquery.js', function() {
                  $.getScript('js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js', function() {
                         $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
                 });
                });
       });

    });
});
```

**The problem is with the third one above:**
 $('#apDiv2').load('ePC.html #content', function () {...

'#content is  id.  ANd the picture is within the  tag within "ePC.html"

```
<div id=content>
<a rel="lightbox" href="images/bird.jpg"><img src="images/bird_s.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

It WORKS 100% on Chorme and Firefox but **NOT Internet explorer 8**!!!!. (I understand why people hate IE now..)
IE crashed!.  I later fixed this crashing problem by removing the !DOCTYPE..within "reviews.html"
Ok with !DOCTYPE removed, IE doesn't crashed anymore. HOWEVER, the lightbox CSS DOES NOT APPLIED to the image!

**Other methods that I have tried but didn't work:**
**1.  "live" instead of "load":**

```
$('#linkEPC2').click(function() {
                    $('#apDiv2').live('load', 'ePC.html, #content', function(){
                     $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
                     $.getScript('js/jquery.js', function() {
                      $.getScript('js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js', function() {
                             $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
                     });
                    });
           });

        });
```

This one doesn't work at all.  Even the image is not there at all.
So I guess I may stick with the "load()" function instead.

**2. I've also tried putting these 3 lines into the div section:**

```
<div id=content>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <a rel="lightbox" href="images/bird.jpg"><img src="images/bird_s.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
```

but it doesn't work neither..

Comment: you're using $.getScript to load js/jquery.js, there's no need for it as you're already using it (this mau cause a conflict), try change the load from: 'ePC.html, #content' to 'ePC.html #content', try attach those script and css in the head manually, remove @ from the selector (I don't think that it will help but :)), let me know :)

Comment: Thx, but I tried it and it doesn't work neither.  Btw, I have to load js/jquery.js o/w the lightbox effect won't work at all.

Comment: Oh yes, it works now!!: I add the css line into the div (without those 2 lines of scripts) and it works on IE now!! Great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and noticed a few things about the jQuery load in IE:

1. It doesn't accept the syntax of '`load("href selector",function()...`' (while chrome and FireFox do accept this syntax).
2. The loaded html should not include  tags.